# What is the name of the lambda-configuration pattern used in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

In ASP.NET core we use this pattern a lot to configure various services.

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.Cookie.Domain = "example.com";
    }
);
```

Does this particular style / pattern using a lambda to configure things have a more formal common name?

Comment: Not sure the lambdas have a name, but the overall thing is the builder pattern. So maybe *builder pattern with lambdas*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of Builder and Option patterns.